# Google Video Intelligence - Custom Labels

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

Does anyone know if it is possible to create your own custom Labels and create new recognition models using Google's Video Intelligence API? For example, supposed I wanted to create a label to identify types of bikes (Specialized, Trek, Cannondale, etc) and these Labels do not already exist. Can I build my own? Google support seems to think so but I see no indication the API supports this.